# Why does Android mark my applications as unsafe?

Tags: installation, apk, side-loading

While downloading unsafe modded .apk files from the internet and while installing them there is no prompt of "unsafe app being downloaded". But when I install an apk that I made, there is a prompt (just a warning that the app that I am installing can be malicious). Why does this happen and how can I prevent it from happening in my applications?

Comment: You have already answered your question. Modding an APK also requires to resign the APK, but now packageName and signer does not match (or the signer is simply unknown to Google) which is by definition suspicious from Google's perspective. You can prevent that by not modding apps.

Comment: "*install an apk that I made*" how did you make the APK though?

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the question. I said that downloading a modded apk from internet which is clearly not the original one gives no warning but if i try to make my own small little app for android it starts giving warnings (and if you are asking i am using buildozer to compile apk and was using python to develop the app(kivy for the frontend))